# Is there a name for analyzing historical societies based on who murders who?

Tags: cultural-history, historiography

When I was in college mumblety years ago, I had a professor who mentioned an interesting idea I'd like to learn more about. While discussing the society of the Roman Empire, she mentioned in passing that one way to analyze a historical society was to look at who was committing the murders, and who they were murdering.

So if the most common murders are fathers killing their sons and vice versa, that tells you that a major point of strain in society was the father son relationship. Likewise if most murders are husbands killing wives or vice versa, that tells you something different.

This was an undergrad survey course, so my professor didn't go into any great detail, and it's long enough ago that I may well be remembering it completely incorrectly. I'm hoping someone can either point me to a name for this concept so my Googling will be more successful, or point me to a good book on the subject.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi Drew C and welcome to H:SE. I found this you might find helpful - you can preview it on Google Books. Not sure if it's precisely what you were looking for, but might help. *Writing the History of Crime* by Paul Knepper https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tmQmCwAAQBAJ&dq=analysing+history+by+murders&source=gbs_navlinks_s